# Shape a triangle with UIView backed by CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cashapelayer

From the tutorial : `http://swiftiostutorials.com/tutorial-draw-nice-triangle-view-border-cashapelayer/`, i managed to create a triangle like :

[image]

```
class Triangle: UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.frame = self.layer.bounds

        let width = self.layer.frame.size.width
        let height = self.layer.frame.size.height

        let path = CGPathCreateMutable()

        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 0, 0)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, width, 0)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, width, height)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, width/2, height)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, width, height)


        mask.path = path
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

But what i'm trying to achieve, is a triangle like :

[image]

How does one do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this path instead:

```
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 0, 0)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, width, 0)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, width/2, height)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0, 0)
```

full class:

```
class Triangle: UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.frame = self.layer.bounds

        let width = self.layer.frame.size.width
        let height = self.layer.frame.size.height

        let path = CGPathCreateMutable()

        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 0, 0)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, width, 0)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, width/2, height)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0, 0)

        mask.path = path
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, didn't notice the extra `CGPathAddLineToPoint`. Thanks, mate !